# Is it possible to convert .master back to .html file?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, master-page, custom-masterpage, conversion

Is it possible to convert a .master page back to .html?

We want to use it for the preview in a page layout. E.g.:

```
<mso:HtmlDesignFromMaster msdt:dt="string">https://my-intranet-website/sites/007/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.html, https://my-intranet-website/sites/007/_catalogs/masterpage/oslo.html</mso:HtmlDesignFromMaster>
```

But adding the .master directly wont work and I'm unable to convert it by hand.

Also we don't have access to the HTML-Source.